# Performance UNION all & joins

Tags: oracle, performance, join, union, sql-execution-plan

I have a sql script that runs approximately 7000 statements such as these:

```sql
select
    (select
         ren.id
     from con_regions ren
     where ren.app_id = &app_prefix.14000
       and ren.pagina_id = 300
       and ren.naam = 'Aantekeningen 1'
       and ren.type = 'region'
       and ren.tabelnaam = 'ovl_lichtpunten') ren_id,
    (select
         pga.id
     from con_paginas pga
              join con_kolommen kom on kom.id = pga.kom_id
              join con_tabellen tbl on tbl.id = kom.tbl_id
     where pga.app_id = &app_prefix.14000
       and pga.pagina_id = 300
       and kom.naam = 'aantekeningen'
       and tbl.naam = 'ovl_lichtpunten')      pga_id
from dual
union all
select
    (select
         ren.id
     from con_regions ren
     where ren.app_id = &app_prefix.14000
       and ren.pagina_id = 300
       and ren.naam = 'Aantekeningen 1'
       and ren.type = 'region'
       and ren.tabelnaam = 'ovl_verdeelkasten') ren_id,
    (select
         pga.id
     from con_paginas pga
              join con_kolommen kom on kom.id = pga.kom_id
              join con_tabellen tbl on tbl.id = kom.tbl_id
     where pga.app_id = &app_prefix.14000
       and pga.pagina_id = 300
       and kom.naam = 'aantekeningen'
       and tbl.naam = 'ovl_verdeelkasten')      pga_id
from dual
union all
```

It currently takes ~10 minutes to create 7000 records from the dual table. I would like to reduce the time as much as possible. I have tried CTE and views, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

The following fields have also been indexed: app_id, pagina_id, kom_id from con_paginas, tbl_id, naam from con_kolommen, naam from con_tabellen.

Explain plan in Oracle looks like this:

[Explain plan Oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZHku.png)

EDIT:

To give a better explanation of my current problem:

The 7000 statements, such as above, are being spooled into a flat file (.txt) and being loaded (inserted) with SQLLOADER into the following table: con_paginas_volgorde_tmp. The first column results are the REN_ID and the other one is PGA_id. These are being splitted by the delimiter ','

The statements are the standard configuration data that are being loaded after every update/patch. Because the original table have custom records from the production environment (apart from the standard configuration data (7000 statements..), I can not simply truncate the original table as this will result in data loss.

Then afterwards I am going to merge that _tmp table with the original table in order to only merge the different records with the MINUS operator and MERGE statement.

[Flat file output & temp table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOZOE.png)

ID column is a sequence

CREATE columns are schema owner and sysdate

UPDATE columns are nulls

Comment: Where do the different literal values come from?  It looks like you could have a table of 7000 literals and just join that to both of your subqueries rather than effectively running each subquery 7000 times with different parameters.

Comment: Those values can be changed due to patches/updates in the near future. The 7000 literals are being stored in a TEMP table and merged with the original table with the MINUS operator. (in order to only merge the differences between the TEMP and original table). Those values are currently static and/or retrieved from other tables such as con_kolommen.

Comment: So there is already a temp table with the 7000 sets of literal values you're using in the various queries that are getting `union all`'d together?  Is there a reason that you're not joining to that table to generate the 7000 values you need here?

Comment: You should describe your problem with something more visually. May be simple example such as images with two simple tables with some rows and just few of attributes is better. Your code just to be more specific your problem in detail.

Comment: I have added some more information in the hopes of a better understanding of my problem.